# ORACLE SQL: JOINS, AGGREGATES, SUBQUERIES

Tags: sql, oracle

For all employees show the department number, employee number, employee name, salary, and the average salary per department.

Please help!

Comment: How are your tables structured? What have you tried?

Comment: School work? (If it is, please mention it in the question...)

Comment: @jarlh - mostly it doesn't matter whether the question is school work.   Sometimes the needs of the curriculum produce requirements which would be rejected out of hand in real life.  But as far as we're concerned, all we should be concerned with is, *is this a question worth answering?*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select department_number, employee_number, employee_name, salary, 
(select AVG(salary) from employee B where A.department_number = B.department_number)
from employees A
```

Assuming you have similar column names

Answer (score 0):

The [analytic version of the AVG() function](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/functions018.htm#SQLRF00609) is ideally suited to this:

```
select department_number
       , employee_number
       , employee_name
       , salary
       , AVG(salary) OVER (PARTITION BY department_number) 
                 as dept_avg_sal
from employee
order by department_number
       , employee_number
/
```

Analytic functions are highly neat.  [Find out more](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/functions004.htm#SQLRF06174).